# Not able to use MedianFilter in Scilab 6.1.1

Tags: image-processing, scilab

So I am trying to perform Non-Linear filtering in scilab using the Median Filter .

```
I_NonLinear=MedianFilter(I_noise,F_NonLinear);
```

I get an error --> Undefined variable: MedianFilter
I have installed scilab atoms image processing modules already.
How to get this filter to work ?

Comment: Which Image Processing toolbox did you install ? SIVP, IPCV, IPD ? This function seems to be part of IPD, but IPD has not been updated for Scilab 6.1.1 (it is only available for Scilab 5.5.2).

Comment: yes, scilab 6.1.1 has IPCV, according to best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this since scilab 6.1.1 doesn't support IPD.

```
 I=imread('lenna.png')
 F_NonLinear=[3,3];
 [m,n]=size(I);
 for i=2:m-1
 for j=2:n-1
 d(i,j)=median([I(i-1,j+1),I(i,j+1),I(i+1,j+1);I(i-1,j),I(i,j),I(i+1,j);I(i-1,j-1),I(i,j-1),I(i+1,j-1)]);
  end
  end
imshow(d)
```